# Node.js + MongoDB this._handle.write(data) bugging in net.js

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I'm working with Node.js + MongoDB for an application. From time to time, just before some AJAX request to the server, I get this error:

```
net.js:434
  var writeReq = this._handle.write(data);
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'write' of null
    at Socket._write (net.js:434:31)
    at Socket.write (net.js:426:15)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/path/to/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection.js:426:26)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:64:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/path/to/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connections/server.js:31:21)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:64:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/path/to/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:78:25)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:64:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/path/to/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connections/server.js:110:12)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:64:17)
```

I use mongoskin for connections from node to MongoDB. My version of node is 0.6.5. Before this, I used to receive an error in `connection.js` only (it simply thrown the error and stopped), but I managed to avoid it by adding the suffix `?auto_reconnect` to the URL of the DB when I instantiate the connection and now I have this whole bunch of stuff.

I have to say that the data in my database is pretty big (like 16MB collections) but I don't think this is the real issue here.

I know I gave very little info, I can say it should in theory happen in a code like this:

```
var nmn_connect = require('mongoose/node_modules/mongodb').connect;
nmn_connect('mongo://localhost:8888/my_db?auto_reconnect', function(err, db) {
        ...
    });
```

Yes, I'm using the node-mongo-native here, this is because with mongoskin I cannot really access the list of collections, which I need for a particular operation in my client. Thus I think the error is caused by that (which I recall it should use `net.js` under the hood).

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of mongodb-node-native do you use? Try upgrading to the latest one. It was a known bug.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, you may be saving my day. How do I check that and how to I upgrade it to the latest?

Comment: check package.json. Anyway, just install the latest one from https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native

Comment: I have it on a server, I'm not sure I know where to put it. Is it inside node_modules/mongodb ?

Comment: You didn't install it using npm?
npm install mongodb